# How to get TextView of an activity in an Adapter class while that TextView is not in row of recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-view, android-context

How to get TextView of an Activity  in  RecyclerViewAdapter class and **TextView is not in layout** of row For  RecyclerView  item.As in RecyclerViewAdapter we override method

```
onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
   NewsModel newsModel=values.get(position);  //to get the current object
        holder.news_title.setText(newsModel.getTitle());
        holder.news_body.setText(newsModel.getDescription());
        holder.news_published_at.setText("Date "+GiveMeDate(values.get(position).getDate()));}
```

and as it get only those which are declared in `ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder`   and ViewHolder  will only get ui that are in `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent, false);`but I want to get ui from activity's layout so that I can update TextView value in Adapter **So please Help to do that work.** Image to reflect Layout is as follows:

[image]

Comment: You could always get the Activity context and do a findViewById

Comment: You should never do that. Your RecyclerView adapter should be responsible only for the UI part displayed in the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Sir GVillani82! your saying is completely  correct that RecyclerView is only responsible for ui those are in row of RecyclerView But Sir I want to get TextView of Activity from context that I have received in constructor of RecyclerViewAdapter Sir how can I get it from Context of Activity in Adapter class.

Comment: You should pass Textview as a parameter in adapter when you pass from activity.

Comment: Sir !Thanks a lot . It is working.Sir I have used an other method for it .I want to get your opinion about it that If I make TextView static in Activity class and declare static getter and setter for it .Is it better to do or not  I mean any effect on memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find that the UI of Activity to be used in Adapter class. We should make 
 it static in Activity  and then  make a static method to update its value, after that whenever we want to change its value from Adapter  we will call that static method with actual parameter and it will be updated .I do it as follows

**In Activity**

```
  public static TextView counter_value;
   public static  void update_counter(String value){
        try{
            counter_value.setText(value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.d("Exception","Exception of type"+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**In Adapter class just call that static method**

```
News.update_counter(String.valueOf(counter));
```

Comment: This is not a Good solution. you should try to implement an interface.

Comment: @InsaneCat can you help me with it. I have created interfaces and used them before but I am not able to understand how to implement an interface to access a textView.

Answer (score 3):

- You should pass Textview as a parameter in adapter when you pass from activity
- Second you should done this by using interface.
- Another option is you can get textview by using Object of Activity.

like this **MyActivity.java**

```
 MyActivity myActivity;
 public TextView tv_name;
```

**Adapter.java**

```
myActivity.tv_name.setText("InsaneCat");
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Please right the green check mark and up the answer so it's helpful to others. @MashhoodQadeerBhatti happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

get it by

```
TextView requiredTextView = (TextView) ActivityName.findViewById(R.id.requiredTextView);
```

Comment: Sir you are really great.In your answer there was  great point that I find to make text field static and then make a static method in My Activity class and the when I call that static method it was working nicely                                        public static  void update_counter(String value){
        try{
            counter_value.setText(value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.d("Exception","Exception of type"+ex.getMessage());
        }
    } and when I call it in Adapter as New.update("counter_value")